# std::tr1::unordered_map is ordered instead

Tags: c++, unordered-map, c++03, tr1

I'd like to have an unordered_map which contains the occurrences of each key; the problem is that, when I print myMap, it's ordered instead. I know it'd be better to use C++11, but I cannot for some reasons I'm not going to explain.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/unordered_map>

using namespace std;
using std::tr1::unordered_map;

main () {
    unordered_map<int,int> myMap;
    int counter, key;

    cin>>counter;
    for (int i=0; i<counter; i++) {
        cin>>key; // Read key from keyboard
        if (myMap.find(key) == myMap.end()) // If key is not already present in myMap
            myMap[key] = 1; // Insert the new key with 1 occurrence
        else
            myMap[key]++; // Increment the current key occurrence
    }
    for (unordered_map<int,int>::const_iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it)
        cout << "[" << it->first << "," << it->second << "] " << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there any guarantee an `std::unordered_map` is **not** ordered? AFAIK, it's implemented with a hash table, so, depending on the hash algorithm, an ordered output is entirely plausible.

Comment: You lack a return value for `main`.

Comment: What is the output you would expect, and what did you get instead (a short example would be a good idea)

Comment: @cad If `main` ends without a return an implicit one is generated.  see 3.6.1(5)

Comment: @NathanOliver I mean the `int` in front of `main`. But you got me, at first I doubted my sanity. :-) Shoot me if I'm still wrong.

Comment: @cad Ah yes the return *type* is missing from `main`.  The return *statement* is allowed to be omitted.

Comment: Ex. input: 5 (counter); 3; 7; 1; 3; 8. expected output: [3,2]; [7,1]; [1,1]; [8,1]. program output: [1,1]; [3,2]; [7,1]; [8,1]. As you see, it sorts by key as if it was a normal map.

Comment: First, `unordered_map` doesn't guarantee any order. That's different from guaranteeing that it is not ordered. Second, the whole `if/else` is superfluous and actually inefficient (because it does two lookups instead of one) - `map[key]` inserts `int()` (i.e., 0) if `key` isn't already in the map.

Comment: @LordSilver You want the order to be untouched? I.e. you want the iterator to iterate the map in the order you inserted the values? That's a case for `std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >` then, but this will be quite slow when searching for a key. Using a vector for storage, as well as a map for key lookup could be a solution, but you need to manage both datastructures simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I've tryed to attain. I'd like the order to be untouched while keeping the best possible performance for searching operations within the data stracture. I thought an unordered_map could be suitable for this purpose.